# Paypal HTML Buttons - Upper limit to payments?

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm having a HTML Paypal Button doing weird things.

It's on a site for Art buyers, and so the range of prices is pretty wild. There are 500$ artpieces to 4000$ art pieces.

When I try to buy the 500$ art piece, everything goes through no problem. But when I try to buy one at 2000$, I get a generic error message.

Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time
Please return to the merchant and choose another way to pay.

Now I know it's not a failure of my form. It's the same form that is loaded every time; there's just the amount_1, item_name_1 and item_number_1 fields that change.

So it makes me think it's something with the price.  Is there an upper limit to transactions in Sandbox mode? or is there an upper limit for Paypal HTML Buttons? I searched, and couldn't seem to find a straight answer to that.

EDIT: As asked by mplungjan, here is a basic try of the code. Only things that vary in both forms are price and name.

https://jsfiddle.net/fredy31/mrfn8e3b/5/

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="3000$ Product">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="3000-product">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="3000">
```

And I've done a bit of research. Tried to find a response to this, but couldn't find a straight answer. What I've found is this: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments-Archive/What-is-the-transaction-amount-limit/td-p/616278 but it says the limit is 10k, and I'm still far from that.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Edited with the requested exemples and results of the research.